# C++ "Maze" Assignment

Tags: c++, maze

The mini-program is supposed to print out all the possible routes through a maze, where the entrance/starting point is always one down from the top left corner and all possible exits that are always on the right wall. It retrieves the maze from a text file.

The maze is actually just a bunch of text.
The maze consists of an n x n grid, consisting of "#" symbols that are walls, and assorted letters [a...z] representing the walkable area/paths. Letters can repeat but can never be side by side.

The maze is 15x15.

An uppercase S always labels the entrance, and is on the left wall in the second highest spot. A possible path is only through letters- you can't walk on # symbols. Any letter on the right wall represents exit(s).

For example,

```
######
Sa#hln
#bdp##
##e#ko
#gfij#
######
```

is a possible maze. My little program is supposed to print out all the possible routes after reading the text file that actually contains the maze.

A call to the program would generate the following output to the screen:

```
Path 1: S,a,b,d,e,f,i,j,k,o
Path 2: S,a,b,d,p,h,l,n
2 total paths
```

How about would I go about doing this? I don't need a complete code answer, I just want some guidance on how to approach this problem.

So far I've done everything except the actual algorithm itself that recursively checks adajcent squares to see if you can walk on them, and I don't know how I'd work on multiple paths.

This is what I have so far (I know my pathcheck is wrong, but I didn't know what else to do):

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

ifstream file("maze.txt");
vector<char> vec(istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), (istreambuf_iterator<char>())); // Imports characters from file
vector<char> path;                      // Declares path as the vector storing the characters from the file
int x = 18;                             // Declaring x as 18 so I can use it with recursion below
char entrance = vec.at(16);             // 'S', the entrance to the maze
char firstsquare = vec.at(17);          // For the first walkable square next to the entrance
vector<char> visited;                   // Squares that we've walked over already

int main()
{
    if (file) {
        path.push_back(entrance);               // Store 'S', the entrance character, into vector 'path'
        path.push_back(firstsquare);            // Store the character of the square to the right of the entrance
                                                // into vector 'path'.

        while (isalpha(vec.at(x)))
        {
            path.push_back(vec.at(x));
            x++;
        }

        cout << "Path is: ";                    // Printing to screen the first part of our statement

        // This loop to print to the screen all the contents of the vector 'path'.
        for(vector<char>::const_iterator i = path.begin(); i != path.end(); ++i)  // 
        {
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
        }

        cout << endl;
        system ("pause");                       // Keeps the black box that pops up, open, so we can see results.
        return 0;
        }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Are you stuck on some aspect of your solution? Have you done the basics, such as reading the maze from a file into a data structure in your program?

Comment: are you allowed to use recursive function?

Comment: I'd use recursion with a list saving current state, and each recursion making 4 recursive calls for the next step.  On each recursion check if the current location has already been visited, and if it's the end block.

Comment: I don't know how to do those, but they're great suggestions.. I'll try to look up how to read a text file first and then figure out the recursion part :) And yes, I can use recursion.

Comment: What about the "Sabdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdefijko" path?

Comment: Right now, you're trying to define `path_check` as a local function inside of main, which isn't allowed. You also have an extra semicolon before its body you need to remove.

Comment: ^^ Got it. I'm just wondering how to recurse this though... I got it to do horizontal paths, but how would I recurse in all directions and handle multiple paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a few things to start:

1. A way of representing the maze in memory -- a "data structure" that's appropriate for a grid like a maze
2. Methods for accessing and manipulating that maze
3. A method of rendering the maze -- perhaps to print out a maze
4. A way of tracking your progress
5. An algorithm for solving the problem at hand

Consider starting with a much smaller maze -- perhaps one that's 3x3 in size -- with a path that goes straight across the map.  Your program should be able to solve that.  Then change the path to curve a bit.  Then make the map bigger.  Make the path harder.  Have some "red herring" branches off the path.

A smaller map, increasing in complexity, should make debugging the effort a lot easier.  (And if you don't know how to use a debugger, having a small problem to start will make learning the debugger easier.)

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The usual way (especially for school assignments) is to deal with it recursively. Start from the designated starting point. Recursively try each possible square from there (above, to the right, below).

The only real "trick" in this is keeping track of which squares you've already visited. One possibility is to save the value in a square as you enter it, and then before you recursively search the other squares, set it to a value that's not used otherwise (e.g., '.' should work in your case).

Comment: @forthewinwin I would also advise you to look at the [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

Comment: For all routes, a flood-fill typ algorithm (either recursive or using a stack) is definitely the way to go. A* only finds a single route.

Comment: I'm trying to make it go in other directions other than just right.. how would I do that? I could increment the position respectively for each direction, but how would I blend in each together?

Comment: @forthewinwin: Handling other directions basically just means recursing in all four directions, into any of them that hasn't already been visited.

Comment: Would I have 4 seperate loops or would they be nested in each other? And I'm guessing I need a seperate array/vector that keeps track of the visited characters, correct?

Comment: @forthewinwin: Generally, you'd have only one loop. As I mentioned earlier, you'd generally modify the data in the maze to track places you've already visited.

Comment: How would I write this? I'm getting the concept but I don't know what code to write. Like I don't know to use isalpha in the loop(s).

Comment: What do you have so far? Have you read the data from the file into an array of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

What I would first do is of course read in the file and place it into a data structure so you can actually work with it. If this is for homework then the assignment is most likely getting you to learn path finding algorithms, try looking up Dijkstra's algorithm and that should get you started.

Comment: I'm thinking of using ifstream to read in the file... now how exactly would I place it into a data structure? I'm new to C++

Comment: @forthewinwin Well lets say you just choose a 2d array as your structure, you would read in the file character by character and place each into the next array position. When you encounter a new line, move to the next row in the array.

Answer (score 1):

A very high-level approach:

Create a tree that describes the paths you can take through the maze.  Print out the ones that end on the right side.

How would you detect a path that wraps around on itself?  (Or will your mazes not have this problem?)

Answer (score 1):

Load the symbols into an array.  Then recursively check each position: can it go up, down, left, right?  From there, you can save those boolean answers as 0 or 1 in a separate array and use that to continue...based on whether your copy array says you can or can not continue in a certain direction.

Also, definitely make some new methods...i usually try to include very little in the main method...

Hope that helps, wish I had time to look at it more...

-P